# How to create a task to show network setting dialog?

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, settings

I'm trying to create a task in Tasker for Android, to show Network Settings dialog.
I haven't problem to create task (Action Intent) to show a web page or send an email.

like this:

ACTION: android.intent.action.View 
CAT: Default
DATA: mailto:name@domain.com
TARGET: Activity

I can't show even the system settings dialog:

PACKAGE: android.settings
CLASS: android.settings.DisplaySettings

But what action class should I use to call the Network Settings (or mobile data settings) dialog? I know, that the AnyCut application can place this shortcut of this dialog to homescreen, so it must be possible to do it in Tasker.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. Solution:

Create new task of type `Misc/Component Intent`

```
Class : com.android.phone.Settings
Package: com.android.phone
Cat: Default
Target: Activity
```